# Rails, updating multiple nested attributes RESTfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, nested-attributes

I've got a question about updating attributes.

I have an user model and also a debt model. How do I make an restful approach to update all debts belonging to a specific user (users/:user_id/debts) so that they are marked as paid (a boolean attribute) from a link on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant fit this action into the 7 REST actions, you have to create a new collection method on the debts model.

```
#in routes.rb

resources :users do
  resources :debts do
    post 'bulk_update', :on => :collection
  end
end
```

In your debts_controller.rb

```
def bulk_update
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @debts = @user.debts
  #etc...
end
```

In your views

```
link_to "Update user's debts", bulk_update_user_debts_path(@user), :method=>:post
```

Something like this, you can add your optional parameters as well to fit in to your task.

Comment: Why are you doing method=>:post and not method=>:put?